# How to create a listView with multiple views in a row.

Tags: android, listview, runtime

I am writing an app that requires the user to enter some details into a form. The form initially has 3 EditText views in a row. When the user enters some data in the last editText, the onFocusChangeListener should initiate a new row.

This is what I want to do. 
How can I create 3 editText views in a single listView row at runtime?

Comment: you need to create a custom listview. Create a custom layout inflate it for each row in listview. its better do have it in xml but you can also create views in getview at run time

Comment: i'll really appreciate if you could tag an example.

Comment: shows us how your listview should look and what you have tried. for example you can search on stackoverflow

Comment: what type of custom layout should it be?? like a relativeLayout??

Comment: depends on how the listview rows should be. could you post a screen shot. you could have linearlayout or relativelayout

Comment: earlier i was trying with a totally different way i.e I was creating multiple relative layouts containing the 3 editTexts on runtime and then putting them in a single scrollView. But then I found on some forums that this method would slowdown the performance of the app as it will have to create a lot of independent layouts. Somebody suggested me by the listView method and so i am trying it now. sorry   but i have never used listView in my project that's why i am asking

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/. try this custom lsitview with image and text

Comment: the link you sent is dead!!! header says "nothing found on.....blah blah blah"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a listView with multiple views in a row, you need to customize your adapter, so it can take the form of your row from a source XML -that you should create- and puts it into your listView, here is an example based on BaseAdapter:

This is your Xml source that contains the form of your Row:

**espaceclientuploadsource.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:addStatesFromChildren="true" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:addStatesFromChildren="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Uplodimage"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bingo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/UploadedProductName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Uplodimage"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/UplodedProductPrice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/UploadedProductName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/UploadedProductName"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/UploadedStatus"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/UplodedProductPrice"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/UploadedProductName"
        android:layout_marginRight="27dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bingo" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageViewDelete"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/UplodedProductPrice"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/UploadedStatus"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/bingo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then you need to create an XML file that containes your ListView:

**espaceclientuploads:**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/submit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="submit"
    android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Next is your adapter, it's role is to use your sourceXML as your row Format,

**UploadedAdapter :**

```
public class UploadedAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{   
List<Article> lesArticles;
DataSource produitSource;
LayoutInflater inflater;
String path= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+File.separator+"Bingo";


public UploadedAdapter(Context context, List<Article> lesArticles) 
{
    inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.lesArticles = lesArticles;

}


@Override
public int getCount() 
{
    return lesArticles.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) 
{
    return lesArticles.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) 
{
    return position;
}

private class ViewHolder 
{
    TextView nomduProduit;
    TextView prixDuProduit;
    ImageView status;
    ImageView imageDuProduit;
    ImageView delete;
}
@Override

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView==null)
    {
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.espaceclientuploadsource, null);
        holder.nomduProduit = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.UploadedProductName);
        holder.prixDuProduit = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.UplodedProductPrice);
        holder.imageDuProduit = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Uplodimage);
        holder.status = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.UploadedStatus);
        holder.delete=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ImageViewDelete);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }

    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    Drawable drawableImage = new BitmapDrawable(bitmapImage);
    holder.imageDuProduit.setImageDrawable(drawableImage);
    holder.nomduProduit.setText(lesArticles.get(position).getNomArticle());
    holder.prixDuProduit.setText(lesArticles.get(position).getPrix());
    holder.delete.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete);
    return convertView;
}
}
```

As you can see, your adapter extends the baseAdapter which is an abstract class, so you need to Override its method.

Finally it's your activity that will display your listView:

```
public class EspaceClientUplodedProducts extends Activity{

List<Article> lesArticle= new ArrayList<Article>();
ListView lvListe;

UploadedAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.espaceclientuploads);

    lvListe= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.UploadListView);
    adapter = new UploadedAdapter(this, lesArticle);
    lvListe.setAdapter(adapter);
    lvListe.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
}
```